# Time zone is not detected when formating datetime

Tags: python, django

I have a string in this format: `Mon Feb 27 2012 13:15:00 GMT+0330 (Iraq Standard Time)` ,I'm going to convert it to this format : `2012-02-27T13:15:00.000` , I've done this:

```
startTime=`Mon Feb 27 2012 13:15:00 GMT+0330 (Iraq Standard Time)`
strp_time = time.strptime(startTime, '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
start = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',strp_time)
```

But it caused this error:

```
unconverted data remains: +0330 (Iraq Standard Time)
```

So,I tryed this to remove `(Iraq Standard Time)` :

```
start=re.sub(r' \(.+?\)$', '', startTime)
strp_time = time.strptime(start, '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
start = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',strp_time)
```

But,I'm getting this error:

```
unconverted data remains: +0330
```

Comment: Why would you strip out time zone information? It's important... If you've got a meeting at 12:00:00 IST and you strip the IST, it's now a meeting at 12:00 UTC - or 3 1/2 hours earlier! Either store everything as UTC and convert it to the users local time for display, or store everything with a time zone and (again) convert to user local for display. Just ignoring a timezone will cause you a world of pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your regex to:

```
start=re.sub(r'(\+.*)|(\-.*)$', '', startTime)
```

It will work as you can also strip out the time zone difference information (+ or -), this should be ok for you as you are discarding the %Z data anyhow.

You should possiblly be able to use %z to get the +0330 time difference, but it doesn't work with my Python version, possibly due to a bug. Which seems to be resolved for Python 3.2 see http://bugs.python.org/issue6641

Comment: tnx,after using your regex It had problem with GMT part and caused this error:unconverted data remains:  GMT , so I dropped GMT with this regex: r' GMT(\+.*)|(\-.*)$' ,it worked!now I have 2 problems:1-how to write a regex to drop each zone like UTC,GMT,etc. 2-Does any problem happen to my website if I don't use time zone?I know anything about time zone.

Comment: It depends what you are using the time for! You could use: `r'(.U.*)|(.G.*)$'` to dispose of everything after and including the letter U or G, which you can probably get away with, because no days or months start with U or G...

Comment: I'm using a jquery event calendar(http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html),and this is the standard time that is used in it.Is it important to use time zone in it?

Comment: Unfortunetly I don't know about jquery event calanders. But I think I've answered your original question?